# TYPO3 - How to build this kind of field type?

Tags: typo3

I would like to extend tt_news with this kind of fields, but I dont know how to. I've tried all fiedl types from Kickstarter and none of them seem to fit with it. Can someone point me to a direction where I can learn how to create them?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an "irre" field. It is TYPE "inline" it is not available trough kickstarter.

See:

- [Wiki](http://wiki.typo3.org/Inline_Relational_Record_Editing)
- [TER (IRRE Tutorial)](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/irre_tutorial)
- [Core Documentation](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tca/4.7.1/view/1/3/#id590095)